URL rewrite issue on .htaccess
Good evening
I'm trying to do an .htaccess with a rewrite url
basically the "short link" will be
mysite.it/I-123456

and it must go to
mysite.it/join.php?invitation=123456

This is the part of the .htaccess involving it
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^I-([0-9]+)\$ join.php?invitation=$1 [NC]

but if I type www.mysite.it/I-123456 I will still landing in the homepage...
this is the full .htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_POST} !www\.mysite\.it$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.it/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^I-([0-9]+)\$ join.php?invitation=$1 [NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.it[NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|php|css)$ - [NC,F,L]

Options -Indexes

what I'm doing wrong?

The backslash in the matching pattern in your rule RewriteRule ^I-([0-9]+)\$ does not make any sense. It makes the pattern match strings the contain a literal ampersand character at that position which is not what you want.
That would be the correct variant:
RewriteRule ^I-([0-9]+)$ join.php?invitation=$1 [NC]

I would suggest a few additional modifications:
RewriteRule ^/?I-(\d+)/?$ join.php?invitation=$1


\d is the special character that matches any digit.
A leading /? allows the same, unmodified rule to be used inside the central configuration of the virtual host (which is the preferred place to implement such rules for various reasons). You can still use that rule in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") as you currently do.
A trailing /? allows for an optional trailing slash in requests. Some situations can lead to that, I see no reason to reject such a request.
The [NC] flag does not really make sense in my eyes. You explicitly show the proposed final URL using a capital "I". So why match case insensitive? You might require [L] flag or even an [END] flag in that rule, though.

You can play around a bit with that rule on a htaccess validator.

Update: In the comment here you now say that this invitation code can contain digits and letters. In your question you only show letters and the rule you implemented also tried to only match digits. So I assumed the invitation code is a number.
Given that we talk about an alphanumeric code you need to match such:
RewriteRule ^/?I-([a-z0-9]+)/?$ join.php?invitation=$1

Or:
RewriteRule ^/?I-([\w\d]+)/?$ join.php?invitation=$1

Here is the updated validator.

Thanks for the correction, but it still doesn't work with the invitation code I'm creating, as I use letters and number :(
I've put as you've suggested:
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^/?I-(\d+)/?$ join.php?invitation=$1
The referral code is, for example
I-3b1b333ba1hgjre
Even using the validator provided (which I love!), the url rewrite doesn't work :(
Can I put instead
RewriteRule ^/?I-(.+)/?$ join.php?invitation=$1 ?

@MarcoScarpa OK, that is different to what I understood from the question. I made an update to the answer.

Can I ask you for an edit?
I'd like to make like: RewriteRule ^/?I/([\w\d]+)/?$ join.php?invitation=$1
so mysite.it/I/ABC123456
but in the redirected page, all the links with a href='../' are now wrong due to this fake folder "I/"... is there any chance to fix it?

I'd say let's leave the answer as it is, since it answers what has been asked. To me it sounds like you again ask something slightly different. Why? In the question you asked about the pattern I-abc1232, now you suddenly write about a patternI/abc123. Which is something else. Now which is it? If you are actually using the slash ("/") as a separator, then why did you ask about a dash in the question? What you can learn from this and your correction above: please, for future questions, be precise when asking question. Absolutely precise.

About your current issue which stems from you apparently using a slash now as a separator: certainly relative references using ../ will be impacted by that. Sure. But that is hard to fix on the server side since it is the client side that interprets such a reference. In other words: a browser that loaded a page via the URL https://example.com/I/abc123 will, when using a reference in that page that points to ../efg actually request https://example.com/efg from the server. This is nothing you can detect on the server side. Nothing you can easily handle by means of rewriting.

So either use the pattern I-abc123 as you wrote on the question, or use other references in your page.

Most important however is another detail: you should not ask me for an edit at all. You are expected to be able to work from the answer I gave to you. You should be able to adapt a given solution to your actual, changed situation. You should be able to do that yourself. That is what the rules are when you ask for help here. This is not a free coding service, you cannot expect to be handed a final solution you just have to copy. You are expected to understand how things work, to learn how to use the tools yourself. That requires effort, sure, but that is expected from you.
